# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. in linux ubuntu

Tags: gradle

rui@rui-System-pumpkin9:~/cordova/Hello$ cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=home/rui/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /home/rui/Android/Sdk
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
...........................................................................................................................................
Unzipping /home/rui/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.5-all/2oz4ud9k3tuxjg84bbf55q0tn/gradle-6.5-all.zip to /home/rui/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.5-all/2oz4ud9k3tuxjg84bbf55q0tn
Set executable permissions for: /home/rui/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.5-all/2oz4ud9k3tuxjg84bbf55q0tn/gradle-6.5/bin/gradle

Welcome to Gradle 6.5!

Here are the highlights of this release:

- Experimental file-system watching
- Improved version ordering
- New samples

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 19s
40 actionable tasks: 40 executed
Built the following apk(s):
/home/rui/cordova/Hello/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
rui@rui-System-pumpkin9:~/cordova/Hello$